# Cannot use particular pins in SAMD21 as Digital Output

Tags: microcontroller, gpio, atmel, atmel-studio

I have moved to Atmel from a run I had with MSP430 series and a tad bit confused at the moment as the pin setup seems quite different.

While handling an SPI device I needed a general IO pin to control the RESET functionality of the external SPI radio module and noticed that from bunch of the pins I am using for similar purposes some do not function as they should.

I have picked some empty pin on the ***SAMD21 Explained*** demo board and in this particular case they were,

- Ext3_PIN_3, 4, 5, 6

here is the pin defs from `samd21_xplained_pro.h`

```
//name Extension header #2 pin definitions
#define EXT3_PIN_3                PIN_PA02
#define EXT3_PIN_4                PIN_PA03
#define EXT3_PIN_5                PIN_PB30
#define EXT3_PIN_6                PIN_PA15
```

Hooking **Ext3_PIN_4** (which is PIN_PA11) to a CRO and executing the commands below right at the start for testing, I get no toggles between 3.3 and 0 **unlike the other 3 pins**.

```
int main(void)
{
    struct port_config pin_conf;
    port_get_config_defaults(&pin_conf);

    /* Configure the pin as outputs */
    pin_conf.direction  = PORT_PIN_DIR_OUTPUT;
    port_pin_set_config(EXT3_PIN_4, &pin_conf);
    port_pin_set_output_level(EXT3_PIN_4, 1);
    port_pin_set_output_level(EXT3_PIN_4, 0);
    port_pin_set_output_level(EXT3_PIN_4, 1);
    port_pin_set_output_level(EXT3_PIN_4, 0);
}
```

I got break points on each `pin_set` line and toggling manually by advancing a single line as I didn't want to initialize the `delay_ms` etc. 
Is there anything obvious that I am missing here?

Comment: @petersmith, I have noticed you have written quite a concise answer for a SAMD21 related question over here. So if possible I would appreciate it if you could have a quick read of my question as well.

Comment: Your `#define` names `PIN_PA11` as `EXT2_PIN_4` but the text names it as `EXT3_PIN_4`.

Comment: How are you checking for the toggles? As the code stands now, the toggling could be happening so fast that you just aren't seeing it. Try adding a delay between toggling.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Just a typo. I have just picked the wrong hash defines for this example just to clarify. I'll fix it in the question. obviously my code has all the #defines defined for the external pins.

Comment: @DigitalNinja , I totally understand what you're saying but I have forgotten to mention that I have put a break point on each line and go through it in a human time scale. 
It must be some issue that I am not aware of. I will update the question to clarify.